# jade extend a page generated without a layout

Tags: node.js, express, pug, extend, block

**My Problem**: I cannot get my jade blocks to extend
**My Setup**: Running the latest NodeJS with Express 3

I'm loading some HTML via Ajax using a Post method

```
app.post "/utilities", (req, res) ->
  res.render "utilities", layout:false
```

In Utilities I have the content, and I'm trying to break up everything into chunks so that this page isn't so busy

```
// utilities.jade

div#topPanel
  section#toolMenu
    block tool // <- won't load

  div#rightPanel
    section#screen
    section#userWindow
      block user // <- won't load

section#chatWindow
  block chat // <- won't load (example case)
```

And lastly I have the individual blocks that follow this structure

```
// chat-block.jade
extends utilities

block chat
  div.inner
    div.left
      form#chat-input
        textarea
    div.window
      div.full
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to [include](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#includes) chunks of jade into your main file.

Change to following code

```
section#chatWindow
  block chat // <- won't load (example case)
```

to

```
section#chatWindow
  include chat
```

and your chat-block.jade to

```
div.inner
  div.left
    form#chat-input
      textarea
    div.window
      div.full
```

Then it works fine!

Comment: AFAIK `include` is the "top-down" approach. You render your main template and this pulls all the subtemplates. `block` on the other hand is more "bottom-up". You render your subtemplate, in this case the chat, and it looks upwards if it is part of a main template with header, footers, etc. and gets this content.